# Why do I get this error in my html code?

Tags: html, css, validation, compiler-errors, stylesheet

I have defined the style "headingcode" in the css stylesheet but when I attempt to validate the webpage where I used the code, I get the following error:

```
Line 15, Column 14: element "headingcode" undefined
<headingcode>Creating My First Document</headingcode><br/>
```

Any ideas on why the validation checker gives me this error? (http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri)

Comment: What if you'd post some of your HTML and CSS code?

Comment: Because `<headingcode>` isn't a valid HTML tag.

Comment: I don't think this "headingcode" is a valid html tag

Comment: Have you considered accepting my answer as the best suitable for your question?

Answer (score 1):

Defining style in the CSS and use HTML tags is completely different. CSS doesn't allow you to create your own HTML tags. In your case `<headingcode>` is not a valid HTML tag. It allows to use specific `IDs` and `classes` to actual HTML tags like so

```
#myDiv
{
    property: value;
}
```

allowing you to use `<div id="mydiv"></div>` (replace `#` by `.` to use `classes`).

Edit : [here's some document on CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) :

Comment: You can use more selectors than just `.` and `#` in CSS.  You can select by tags too `div{ /* */ }`.